# Finding the Plot Coordinates from the Scatter Plot Data

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlay

So I want to annotate a plot of points in an ellipse by embedding a graph on top of each of the points. I have done this manually with the first few points via the inset axes function.

[image]

For instance, I plotted the graph with the line via:

```
        ins = ax.inset_axes([0.45,0.015,0.1,0.1])
        xxx = numpy.arange(10)
        yyy = numpy.arange(10)
        ins.plot(xxx, yyy)
```

I placed all the graphs manually so far, but this is tedious, and if the points change, then my code is invalid. Let's say the green circle in the above plot was plotted using:

```
        ax.scatter(green_x, green_y, marker="o", s=50, edgecolors="green", c="green")
```

**Question**

How can I find the ax.inset_axes() coordinates for the green circle in the plot above so that I can overlay my graph automatically?

Comment: The position of the green dot in ax coordinates is `x, y = ax.transAxes.transform((green_x, green_y))` so the inset ax attached to that dot from its bottom-left corner will be `ax.inset_axes([x, y, 0.1, 0.1])`.

Comment: @Guimoute When I do that, I get the following for a few points: 

[250.0 175.99999999999997]
[-984.6308000000001 175.99999999999997]
[1484.6308000000001 175.99999999999997]

That doesn't seem quite right. It doesn't show up on the plot anyway.

Comment: My bad, I missed a step. We want to turn data coordinates in figure coordinates then in axes coordinates. `xf, yf = ax.transData.inverted().transform((green_x, green_y))` then `xa, ya = ax.transAxes.transform((xf, yf))`.

Comment: @Guimoute Got it -- I used trans = (ax.transData + ax.transAxes.inverted()).transform((green_x, green_y)) but I get it. Thanks! Did not know about transformations before.

Comment: Glad it worked! Yes transformations are awesome when you need to place objects at relative positions. You just need to be careful if the figure is resized or the data x/y limits change, the objects might now adjust automatically depending on how you created them.